# iOS app (MobileFirst) is rejected by Apple (NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription)

Tags: ios, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst, ios10, testflight

Our hybrid mobile app for iOS (that is developed with MobileFirst 7.1) was rejected recently by Apple:

> This app attempts to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description. The app's Info.plist must contain an NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data.

However, the app does not use Photo Library. So, the issue should come from one of the libraries we use. Besides CordovaLib (that comes with MobileFirst), we use email-composer (cordova-plugin-email-composer), PushPlugin (https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin) and barcodescanner (https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner). Barcodescanner requires camera access (the key was included to Info.plist before submission), but not photo library access. For the other two plugins there is no information on their web pages about iOS 10 and their use cases is too far away from Photo Library.

So, the questions are:

- can cordovaLib cause such an issue? (MobileFirst)
- is camera access somehow connected to photo library? (e.g. camera usage implicitly needs access to photo library)
- how to check what exactly causes such issues? Is there a tool that can tell in advance that using of some class will cause issues with privacy settings?

P.S. I know that I can just add NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription key to Info.plist, but thats not what I want: the app does not need photo library and I don't want to add such a key.
Can not post a link to email-composer due to stack overflow restrictions.

Comment: Do MobileFirst provide their own way of accessing camera?

Comment: No. The SDK uses Cordova however Hybrid apps are generated by MobileFirst tools (for example, the project's config.xml file which defines plugins).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it is the answer: embedded Cordova plugins that comes with MobileFirst caused problems. Submission to TestFlight without barcodescanner but with these plugins failed with the same issue. Removing embedded plugins solved the problem and submission was accepted.

https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2016/10/25/supporting-privacy-changes-in-ios-10/

P.S. It is not clear why there were only problems with Photo Library and not with Contacts, for example, but anyway it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a blog post discussion why this happens: http://cordobo.com/2256-fix-ioniccordova-app-ios-10-nscamerausagedescription-permission/. The author happens to also use a barcode scanner, and Cordova. It's pretty much the same case.

This is a change that now happens due to new a policy by Apple starting iOS 10.

Unlike the blog post, which suggests to remove and re-add the camera plug-in - since in MobileFirst you cannot do this action on your own, I suggest to do the change manually. By change I mean adding the description tag, with your desired text, in the config.xml file and attempt again to submit the application.

If it fails still, I then suggest to open a PMR for the IBM support to help out.

Also note that there may be additional plugins that will require the description text treatment. Look at the following changelog by Apache Cordova in a recent blog post. Search for iOS changes.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! It is not exactly what I am looking for. I knew that barcode plugin requires camera and I already added the key to Info.plist before submission. As far as I understand, changes to config.xml file will just add the key to Info.plist automatically after rebuilding the environment. The problem is with photo library access, not camera access. I can not really understand what plugins need photo library, because we don't use it in our project. It is not a problem to add the key with description, the problem is to understand what plugins use it implicitly.

Comment: From what I can understand barcode requires camera and camera potentially requires gallery. I think it all goes together. You can't separate the need AFAIK. The Cordova community may know more, but this is also way I suggested for you to open a PMR.

Answer (score 0):

Update you **Info.plist** file by adding permission base on your **rejection mail** or error log.

**NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription**

```
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) photos and video use.</string>
```

### OR

***Resolving the Privacy-Sensitive Data App Rejection***

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1937/_index.html